Feedback requested: How do you use tag hover descriptions for curating and do you use the RSS feed feature?
Update August 28, 2024
We appreciate the time everyone took to share their feedback. Based on that and a conversation with the moderators we had on this last week, we will be keeping the variant B tag as mentioned here, but reverting it to show the old tag usage guidance as they were before.
We still believe that a simplified tag description on the hover makes sense for new site users. That said, it doesn’t make sense for all users. So, we are proposing this be controlled as a profile setting managed on the preferences page. Brand new users would default to getting the simplified tag hover state. Those who wish to curate could use this as an option to see the tag excerpt on the hover. This would likely look pretty close to the images below.
We also don’t want to force too many people to enable this setting themselves, so we are considering some criteria for who to enable it for automatically. We would love to hear your ideas on who should get it. We thought maybe those with the custodian badge would be a good group to turn it on for, as it means they have taken some form of curation activity. If you have a different suggestion let us know.



Last week, we updated you on how our tag hover experiments went. Some of the feedback we received was unexpected, so we have some follow-up questions to better understand what was shared.
Tag hover descriptions as a means of curation
Some of the feedback left by curators was not something we had considered, specifically, relying on the tag hover descriptions to help them curate. We assumed that curation activity was done on tags in which users have expertise, so referencing the tag usage guidance was not something a curator would need to do in most cases. That being said, based on the feedback received, it appears that isn’t the case. To this point, we would like to know more about where tag hover descriptions fall in curation workflows.

If you rely on tag usage guidance to assist in curation, are you doing this in the review queue? Or are you just browsing around the site and checking hover descriptions on questions you come across? Or something different?
How often do you find that you need to actually change the tag on a post?

RSS feeds and their use
Currently, we understand that RSS feeds are not a significantly used feature and that generally, there is declining support for them on the web. Historically, the easiest way to get to them was on the tag hover, but a link to subscribe can still be found under the HNQ list on the tagged questions page. We didn’t anticipate people feeling strongly about them due to their low use, so we would like to know what you are using them for and how frequently.

Why RSS feeds? What value are they currently providing that you can’t find on the site?

Next steps
Based on the feedback we receive here we will update you on the tag hover post if it leads us to make any changes to what we have already stated there. We will be reviewing feedback left on this post until August 29th, 2024.

"we understand that RSS feeds are not a significantly used feature and that generally, there is declining support for them on the web." citation needed. I don't use RSS feeds on [so], or any of the other sites in the community, but this feels like a sweeping statement and the RSS is in decline across the board; I subscribe (and continue to subscribe) to RSS feeds for blogs, news, and podcast feeds. RSS might be in decline on the network, but I'm not sure it's in decline on the web [as a whole].

What value are they currently providing that you can’t find on the site? I'm always surprised you ask us for data you have at your fingertips: Feeds. Or do you really hope I go write a scraper to list every chatroom across 3 chat servers that has Tag Feeds configured on them? Ask balpha. He can help.

I hope this RSS feeds thing isn't driven by an attempt to reduce cost of ingress. I can't imagine having the RSS reader call out every 15 minutes makes that much of an impact. If that assumption is wrong, please share the numbers and/or motivation.

@rene The only change to the RSS feed in play is to remove the RSS button from the tag hover. There are no plans to remove RSS support anywhere else.

Okay, I might have misunderstood the change then. That is good to hear. So only UI discoverability changes.

In the meantime, while you await feedback here and decide what to do next, can you please revert the tags to the original functionality (AKA showing the tag wiki excerpt on hover of tags)?

Why asking 2 different questions in one topic? With a single question "Is RSS feeds useful for you", you could post 2 answers, kind of poll, "yes" and "no" and we would just upvote one of them. Or you can phrase the question "Lets remove RSS feed button from tag tooltip" and those who like the idea will upvote and who dislike - downvote. Am I supposed to post my own answer to all your questions? Because we need many combinations of answers in single post for me to choose one and upvote: rss - yes/no, tag hover - using/not using, tag change - often/rarely...

Why is it that, even when acknowledging that we actively use the excerpt, you [SE] decide to move forward with a Brilliant Idea:tm: to remove excerpts from tag wiki pages too?

Y'all, stop trying to close staff questions soliciting feedback.  It prevents the community from giving important feedback, and also, this question is in fact adequately focused: it's asking about usage of items on the tag hover.

Sbd to edit the Qt for a direct Link onto the 'Custodian' Badge...? => "Complete at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type."... // End of the week (Saturday), I still don't have any Setting about "Show tag user guidance in tag hover"... // I don't do any 'Staging Ground' Reviews anymore until this has been activated, and I stopped doing Reviews when the Tag Excerpts disappeared..., just saying...

I improve tags constantly, and it infuriates me when they are empty or badly written.  RSS I don't know or care or use.


We assumed that curation activity was done on tags in which users have expertise, so referencing the tag usage guidance was not something a curator would need to do in most cases.

I might be active and familiar with, say, javascript. That does not mean I know every single other tag used with it.
Consider, for example, the tag spread which can be found on some questions: javascript spread might make sense on the surface because there is JavaScript spread syntax. However, hovering over the second tag used to show:

This tag relates to the R spread function. For the javascript spread syntax - please use spread-syntax.

which tells me this is not the JavaScript feature. And that the correct tag would be spread-syntax. I have had to look this up a lot because I cannot remember the exact correct tag (other alternatives might be "javascript-spread" or "es6-spread").
For the record, on hover spread now reads:

Some of the features are: Powerful Formula Engine with 300+ Excel Functions Full Excel Import/Export, PDF, and Print Support Input, Display, and Data Visualization Controls Visual Drag-and-Drop Designers

There are many tags that might refer to a library/framework/other technology that I have never even heard. They might be JS-related - I would know when I hover. I might also hover over them and find out they are wrong.
The notion that I would only change the tag javascript because that is the only one I know seems to ignore any other tag that might exist. No, I am not opening questions with tags completely unfamiliar to me and trying to puzzle out how to use them for the first time. I still encounter tags which are new to me.

If you rely on tag usage guidance to assist in curation, are you doing this in the review queue?

I do not tend to use the review queues a lot. But if I do, I would try to check the tags.
On the rare occasions I check something in the staging ground, I check whether the tags they used are correct. Again, I do not know every single tag by heart. Even if I check a question with tags I do know - there are up to 4 other tags.

Or something different?

I mostly use custom filters. It is the only sane way to properly follow tags. Often enough somebody tags a question jquery only with no other tag. Even if they actually have a question about JS syntax (e.g., loop, if, some other non-jQuery construct).
I have one filter for tags that generally interest me. I check the new questions there and potentially take action like: vote, comment, close vote, edit, answer.
I also have many filters created for problematic tags or tag combinations.

Some of them I monitor for any new entries that show up.
some I just visit occasionally. Maybe every week or two.
Some I intend to eventually visit and clean up, so I do not monitor them but they serve more as a bookmark.
Some I have cleaned up but still keep an eye on for new entries.

I keep adding new custom filters when I find something which has very high likely hood of being wrong, often some tag pairing of two mostly incompatible tags.
I also use the tag ignore feature for a similar effects. For some tags that are more sporadic. It makes it easy to identify the odd question that potentially misapplies the tag by sight.

How often do you find that you need to actually change the tag on a post?

A LOT!!! There are so many wrong tags already used. Searching for [javascript] [spread] finds 103 questions.
That 103 is tiny, [javascript] [fetch] finds 3993 questions where it should be exactly zero. And probably a lot of these should have used fetch-api instead.
There are many more. Say, every single api (95k questions) or web (44k questions) usage should be something else instead.
I have gone through pages and pages of questions tagged regex design-patterns removing the latter because all but 5 used design pattern because they wanted a regular expression pattern.
But even just incoming questions - again it is a lot. The questions posted daily tagged api are a dozen or two, at least. Every other day or so, there is a new question tagged dsa which is not about the subject of the tag: the Digital Signature Algorithm. Instead, (almost exclusively) new users use it for "Data Structures and Algorithms" when they have a question for...at best one of these (but also commonly: neither. Just used as "something about programming" tag).
There are also regularly questions about Java tagged javascript or about JavaScript tagged java.
Many questions seems to be about Amazon Lambda yet tagged with lambda in addition or even instead. Search finds 1.5k collective:"AWS" [lambda] is:q and I would hazard a guess at least half should only have aws-lambda. If not 90%.
About once a week perhaps we get a question tagged typescript2. The tag refers to TypeScript version 2, which was released in 2016. However, the latest version is 5.6 and all the latest questions are not about the old release. Users just have questions about TypeScript - whatever current version they use (say, might be few minor versions behind, at most).
And so on. I hope I managed to convey that we have lots of tags that get regularly misapplied.

In summary, there are two categories of questions where I would change a tag - old and new:

old - there are hundreds of thousands, probably even millions, of questions that have misused tags in some way or another. There is not enough manpower on Stack Overflow to handle this. Even the occasional burnination is a drop in the ocean.
new - there are questions all day, every day that are posted with the wrong tags. We do not have enough manpower to stem that tide, either. So they seep in and pile up with the old ones all the time.

And we have not even talked about the new tags being created all the time. Takes no effort to do that and many users seem to create new tags even by accident.

Tag edits are probably my main type of edits indeed. Especially minor things as [tag:python-3.x] to [tag:python]. I even have a canned comment for people that forgot to tag their question with a language. If I can figure out what they are using (tag in title, mentioning it somewhere in the text etc) I add it myself, otherwise I just leave it with the comment for the OP to figure out themselves.

RSS feeds specifically are still important for SO's chat, given it has a built-in feature to consume an RSS feed and post what comes through it into a channel. whether or not that matters for an rss feed button existing in a popup? :shrug:, if it's at least available on the tag wiki I don't think anyone will care that it went away on the popup.
They need to exist for inter-operability between Stack sites and other tools, whether they are tools that exist on stack or not.

granted... id argue the rss feed from a search result is more useful for this purpose, given you can filter and sort it. ;) that rss feed is down at the bottom of the right column. It's missing on tag wiki pages

We were just talking (joking) about getting SO to make some improvements for chat. I guess we should settle for asking them not to make it worse.

Yeah, I don't consume the RSS feeds in any way that one could directly detect, but I do consume them via them being posted to SO chat rooms.  In fact, it's how I found this question.

@M--SavetheDataDump We don't have any plans to end support for RSS feeds, just removing the button off the tag hover.

@SpencerG that's good. However, questions that you've put forward sound like you think RSS is done and dusted: e.g. "Why RSS feeds?" Questioning the usefulness of features, with some level of prejudice, leads to ending the support for them (obviously I am not saying you are aware of those plans personally; they most probably don't exist at the moment, but that's just how it works down the line #CP).

I would assume this was more of a one-off "That icon isn't necessary, few people use RSS anymore" decision as opposed to "As a company we're moving away from RSS". It's certainly important that we make it clear that the community still uses the RSS feeds, which i think we've done, but i'm not really concerned with losing this one icon

@SpencerG also see Cody's comment under Zoe's answer.

The hover text being the wiki excerpt rather than the wiki was better for the Suggested Edits review queue, especially when the edits are just adding more general tags. For example, api says "DO NOT USE", or sql requests to use a specific DBMS' tag instead.
If you're in a review for added tags, and you aren't skipping, you'll generally know what the tags are for, but you wouldn't know if there's any restrictions on their usage unless you've used it / seen it before.

As a hypothetical, imagine an edit which adds javascript to a question that uses TypeScript. I personally can tell the difference between Typescript and JavaScript, but I've never looked into the tags, nor asked or answered any questions relating to JS/TS. I wouldn't know if typescript questions should also be tagged javascript unless I read the usage. Hovering over the tag in the review page shows

JavaScript (a dialect of ECMAScript) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed, and interpreted language traditionally used for client-side scripting in web browsers.

which doesn't tell me the answer, I have to leave the page and go to the JavaScript tag page directly, which actually gives me my answer in the wiki excerpt:

For questions about programming in ECMAScript (JavaScript/JS) and its different dialects/implementations ... Include all tags that are relevant to your question: e.g., [node.js], [jQuery], [JSON], [ReactJS], [angular], [ember.js], [vue.js], [typescript], [svelte], etc.

So this edit would be valid.

If you don't know what a tag is at all, skipping is the far better option, not reading the tag wiki.

+1 for mentioning the "DO NOT USE" tag wiki excerpts. These should be more prominant IMO, especially in the suggested edit queue and the Staging Ground.

@dan1st - presumably, now that the UI has been improved for creating/editing tag warnings, such messages can be turned into warnings fairly easily and will appear in the right sidebar during the review phase of the question asking process - whether that's sufficiently visible is another issue but it's at least visible without hovering over the tag.

@Catija From your recollection, is the improved UI for creating/editing tag warnings a CM feature? (I'm envisioning lots of [status-review]'d meta posts per site asking for tag warnings to be created)

@Robotnik my info is incomplete since the project had not been built yet. The core goal was to build a UI that would give CMs most of the things needed to add, remove, and update tag blocks and warnings without dev involvement. Mods can actually see the UI in the updated block list admin page but don't have the ability to edit. One of my stretch goals for the project was to add a site setting that would allow specific trusted mods to at minimum edit/add/remove warnings, though likely not blocks. Did they never announce the changes, even on the mod team?

Alternatively, create a mod tool to request/propose these elements that a CM would only have to approve. Either way, the goal was to avoid the meta escalation process for what would likely be easiest to handle in bulk rather than one request at a time. I'd be tempted to ask on MsE what the process/UI is since they haven't managed to announce it yet.

Tag wikis

We assumed that curation activity was done on tags in which users have expertise, so referencing the tag usage guidance was not something a curator would need to do in most cases

You've already acknowledged that this isn't the case, but I'd like to explain why this isn't the case.
A lot of editing is done by people who aren't necessarily experts in the domain. This especially applies when questions get mistagged, which happens regularly.
Aside day-to-day stuff, this is especially relevant during burninations; when we get rid of tags and try to figure out what other tags to replace the tag with, tag wikis and collective expertise are both used to determine what tags to use.
Personally, even within areas I have expertise in, I still often rely on tag wikis to determine whether a tag is what I think it is. Tag names, as you'll find out if you poke around burninations and disambiguation requests, are complicated because naming stuff is hard. We have lots of bad tags, and there's lots of libraries/etc. with the same name, but that aren't the same library.
One important thing to remember here is that expertise in the domain and expertise in the tagging system are two very different beasts. Even if you assumed someone was the #1 expert in a field, they might not know how to tag correctly, because the tag system is not as straight-forward as "take the name of the thing and insert it in the tag box".
Tag wikis and especially their excerpts are not meant to help people who lack expertise in a field, but to help people who don't understand which tag is for what. If tag wikis were properly displayed to all users, then in a best-case scenario, everyone would read the tag wiki excerpt before tagging to understand what tags are correct to use.
The times I don't look at a tag wiki aren't for my areas of expertise, but for areas where I've previously read the tag wiki, and therefore remember what the tag is for.

If you rely on tag usage guidance to assist in curation, are you doing this in the review queue? Or are you just browsing around the site and checking hover descriptions on questions you come across? Or something different?

The vast majority of my use is from the inline editor or inline tag editor (depending on whether or not the question itself also needs edits) directly on the question page. I then type a tag name and read the description there. It's very rare that I do any editing from the queues at all, but I also don't use the queues that much in general.
The rest is a combination of searches in tooling (particularly the synonym tool), and going to questions with relevant tags to see if it applies elsewhere, and hovering over tags. Though the latter is mainly for burninations when I write the initial list of replacement tags, and not something I usually do outside this particular use-case.

How often do you find that you need to actually change the tag on a post?

When I'm actually actively editing (which mostly stopped in June last year), many times per day, excluding burnination-related edits. There's a lot of incorrectly tagged questions, with many major patterns of incorrect tagging.
As one example of this, see Why are so many people abusing the IDE tags? and the related Can there be tag warnings for [android-studio] and [visual-studio]?
Also worth noting that in spite of the (now less-visible) warnings, there's still plenty of mistagged questions, because getting people to use the right tags from the get-go is both very important and very difficult, especially when the tagging UX hasn't been updated probably ever.
RSS feeds

Why RSS feeds? What value are they currently providing that you can’t find on the site?

RSS feeds are standardised, and useful for subscribing to stuff without having to write an entire API app to read questions. I can take RSS feeds from practically any site on the internet, and use it in the same reader software without having to make any adjustments.
It means that if I want to monitor a tag because I'm waiting for something, I can just drop it into my RSS reader, and I get a notification on my phone when something new appears. I mainly find this to be useful on meta, but that's just where I use it.
The site itself does have this via question listing pages, but it requires active attention to go there and monitor.
And as Kevin already mentioned, chat is a solid use-case. There's many moderation or meta-oriented rooms (including the meta room, the burnination room, SOCVR, and those are just some of the rooms on chat.SO alone) that make use of feeds, as well as several sites that get question feeds from the main site into chatrooms on chat.SE.
It is definitely a niche use-case, but it has a lot of value for those use-cases.

Also: you note that RSS feeds have declining support on the web, but there's lots of dedicated software to it anyway. It's one of the few ways it's possible to have subscriptions to stuff without the site having a dedicated subscription system. As an example, I subscribe to the Linux Mint blog via RSS. They didn't need to implement a fancy subscription system to do it - it just works via standardised RSS software.
There's also a few email clients that have RSS readers, including Thunderbird. It may be losing support in browsers, but it's still far from being so practically dead it isn't worth supporting anymore.
Where exactly the button is isn't a super-big deal, as long as it's somewhere easily accessible. I'm not sure if the sidebar necessarily is that place, but that also works. Having it on the tag wiki page (possibly in addition to the sidebar) might also be useful for consistency.

It sounds like one of their goals is to reduce the clutter in the pop-ups, and, in that case, removing the RSS feed button from the tag pop-up seems eminently reasonable. Just put it on the full tag page. Experienced/power users who want to get to the RSS feed will still be able to do so, and this "advanced" feature won't be cluttering up the pop-ups for other users.


We still believe that a simplified tag description on the hover makes sense for new site users.

Those who have contributed tag metadata over the years have generally done so bearing in mind the usage of the various metadata items in the UI.  By and large, the usage guidance for each tag was written as it was because we believed that to be necessary and appropriate for conveying how the tags should be used.  That's what "usage guidance" is for, after all.  This is useful to all users, but targeted especially at those having little familiarity with our tags, new users most of all.
It may be that some tags' usage guidance could bear simplifying edits. You are more than welcome to assign staff to identifying those tags and making edits through the ordinary community process.  But swapping out the existing usage guidance wholesale for other data intended for a different purpose is so clearly wrongheaded that I really don't understand how we got to this point.
The community has already asserted that the usage guidance we wrote is what should appear on hover.  We wrote it largely for that very purpose.  If SO is really trying to tell us "you did it wrong" then I have a few choice words for you that I will refrain from publishing on the Internet.  Use your imagination.

That said, it doesn’t make sense for all users. So, we are proposing this be controlled as a profile setting managed on the preferences page. Brand new users would default to getting the simplified tag hover state. Those who wish to curate could use this as an option to see the tag excerpt on the hover. This would likely look pretty close to the images below.

No, no, and again no. I'm really having trouble understanding what the disconnect is here. The usage guidance we already have is especially for new users.  It is useful to more experienced users for curation, too, but the point is in large part to reduce the amount of curation work needed in the first place, by supporting better tag accuracy from the get-go.  Is this somehow hard to understand?


If you rely on tag usage guidance to assist in curation, are you doing this in the review queue?

Yes.

Or are you just browsing around the site and checking hover descriptions on questions you come across?

Also yes.

Or something different?

Also also yes. Burninations and tag cleanups are two cases that others have mentioned. Other cases might be someone who specifically links to a question and asks for input (whether from a tag usage perspective or otherwise).
In general, for any Stack Overflow question that I open, there's a good chance I'm looking at the tags and other aspects of the page, consciously or not, and making mental note of whether edits to the tag list or post body/title are warranted.

How often do you find that you need to actually change the tag on a post?

Hard to provide concrete numbers without diving into SEDE but I would guess at least half of the question I view, or edit, involve a tag edit. Many of my edits are specifically to edit a tag or spurred by noticing incorrect tags (which then prompts me to look further at the question, and at the tag page, for other things/other questions to fix).

"Hard to provide concrete numbers without diving into SEDE" FWIW, there is a query Most frequent tag editors and running it shows you as #13 with 20626 tag edits.

@VLAZ Thanks, although I was thinking specifically as a percentage of my total edits or page views, not just the number of times I've made a tag edit. That query is useful, though. Does it include results where the tags were changed and other edits were made, too, or does it just count tag-only edits?

No idea. I just stumbled upon it few days ago and ran it out of curiosity. When you mentioned SEDE now, I recalled I saw your name towards the top.


We assumed that curation activity was done on tags in which users have expertise

In general yes, I curate more on tags I'm familiar with. But I do come across random posts during burninations, in the review queues, etc...

so referencing the tag usage guidance was not something a curator would need to do in most cases

With over 50.000 tags in the system it's all the more common the more you curate.

If you rely on tag usage guidance to assist in curation, are you doing this in the review queue? Or are you just browsing around the site and checking hover descriptions on questions you come across?

Anytime everywhere. If I'm unfamiliar with a tag I'll quickly check the guidance. If I'm editing I'll retag for sure. If I'm voting to close a post I might take the opportunity to also retag; in those cases a quick inspection of the tag guidance using hover can be enough. That under 1 minute action goes a long way in organizing mistagged posts - and mistagging posts is a common problem on both low-traffic and high-traffic tags.

How often do you find that you need to actually change the tag on a post?

Depends on the OP, if they're experienced there's a reasonable chance. If they're inexperienced it's (very) likely.
If you want a hallmark example that gives a rough estimate, the python-3.x tag clearly states in its guidance (I added the bold):

DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag.

But if you check how many Qs are only tagged python-3.x without the parent python:

[python-3.x] -[python]

That's 137,280 out of a total 343,118 Qs. So 40%! Run a SEDE query to correlate that with OP reputation at time of posting and you'll get a significant sample of how common mistagging is.

Ah yes, Python 3-x to Python is one of my most common, if not most common, edit. I've got a canned message for that by now, although I doubt it helps much

If only they implemented a parent tag/language feature instead of stuff like this, the Python and other language version tag issues could magically disappear overnight

Even with this being a setting, I still don't quite understand the purpose of this change. Tags are there to organize posts, they aren't there to teach users what a given technology is. They aren't a good place for documentation, or wiki content, at best the wiki page can contain a short-form overview of what a given language or tool is, but the overarching purpose of tags is still simply to organize content... not to teach users what a given technology behind the tag is.
Why is it so important that we show new users an explanation of what a technology behind a tag is rather than how we are using that tag to organize content? Is there some SEO juice we gain from doing this? some other purpose?


Brand new users would default to getting the simplified tag hover state


That information is still not universally useful. For many tags the "simple" information you get is useless.
There are also many tags that do not have any wiki information. But have an excerpt.


We still believe that a simplified tag description on the hover makes sense for new site users.

Related to point 1. from before, let us look at a few examples:
dom

The current DOM standard is at https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/.


pdf

The official ISO Specification (ISO 32000-1, a.k.a.


spread

Some of the features are: Powerful Formula Engine with 300+ Excel Functions Full Excel Import/Export, PDF, and Print Support Input, Display, and Data Visualization Controls Visual Drag-and-Drop Designers


Do correct me if I am wrong, but I suspect the examples here are not what you mean when you say it makes sense for new users. Thus, if that is indeed not the case, somebody has to update the tag information for new site users. And this is still forced on the community, because we also prefer anybody to have useful information. Not a clipped or incomplete 
Seems at the conclusion of all of this, we are still handed over a massive cleaning job to retroactively justify the claim by SE that the new tag descriptions bring value. That would only be the case after vetting all of it ourselves.
Or is SE willing to step up and do any of this work? To actually make sure the useful content they want to show to new users exists?

It's still a fallacy to think that new users need a definition of terms that are so commonly-used in the field that they have become tags on our Q&A site. What users need is a description of how that tag is meant to be used on this site, and that's exactly what the tag usage guidance is meant to contain. If it's a term that's ambiguous, then the usage description needs to have a description, too. But there is just no need to define what a PDF or a DOM is to a user who is new to Stack Overflow, unless you assume that all users new to SO are also new to computers and programming.

@CodyGray the examples are meant to show tag wikis that are not suitable as hover information for tags. I just picked the first two I found to demonstrate my claim that the new information is not necessarily useful. Also, I don't think "being a tag" makes it automatically clear what is meant by that tag - I often have to check because I might know something else named like the tag. For example, there is [spread] - after reading the hover description, I'd be inclined to believe it's not about JS spread syntax. But I wouldn't know what it is. It's often used in JS questions, though

I'm not involved in the minutiae of tag wikis or the tag hover experiment, but here's one data point.
The [floating-point] tag, which I follow, used to have a nice capsule description:

Floating-point numbers are approximations of real numbers that can represent larger ranges than integers but use the same amount of memory, at the cost of lower precision. If your question is about small arithmetic errors (e.g. why does 0.1 + 0.2 equal 0.300000001?) or decimal conversion errors, please read the tag page before posting.

Some of the ways this text was displayed were mildly problematic, because the user experience surrounding terms like "tag page" and "tag wiki" is problematic.  I've always wished we could fix that somehow.
But now something seems to have gotten much worse, because on a page like this, the nice, capsule description has been replaced by the basically useless "Many questions asked here about floating-point math are about small inaccuracies in floating-point arithmetic".  (I mean, that doesn't say anything.)
This is more of a long-form comment than an answer to the question.  I don't really know what "Tag hover descriptions as a means of curation" means.  My interest is in how descriptive tag text gets displayed and linked on questions pages and the like.
